# Whats wrong with this Code while appending a list with a function?

Tags: function, python-2.7, loops

```
def listc(favn):
    num = 0
    while num < favn :
        num += 1
        return num

list = []
i = int(raw_input("Input your favourite number : > "))  
for num in range(0,i):  
    list.append(listc(i))
print list
```

The elements of the list are just same. Little iterations in code are sometime printing `[None]` in `list` also.

I want to generate a list with content as 1 to i.

Comment: Your code does exactly what it does. If you input a number `n`, let's say 10, it will put ten `10` elements in the list. Maybe you could state what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to generate a list with content as 1 to i

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues with your code.

First the while loop does not run 'favn' no. of times because the return statement is within while loop.It just runs single time, and everytime it returns 1.

Also, you should change

```
for num in range(0,i):  
    list.append(listc(i))
```

to

```
for num in range(0,i):  
    list.append(listc(num))
```

You will get the output you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate a list from 1 to i, you can simply do `list = range(1, i + 1)`.